# Insert large blocks of code into MySql

Tags: php

I'm currently stuck trying to insert a particular type of user input into my MySQL database. I'm creating a form that allows the user to input Title, Requirements, Description, and PowerShell Script code into a database. I need to be able to then display the new input.

I started by converting all my $_POST data into htmlentities before inserting it and everything seemed to be working perfectly. All the short PowerShell scripts were inserting into the database and then displaying appropriately. But, when I tried to insert a long PowerShell script, it just left the table column blank.

```
    // Create Insert SQL prepared statement
    $insertSql = $pdoConn->prepare('INSERT INTO scripts (ScriptID, script_name, script_requirements, script_description, script_code) VALUES (NULL, :scriptName, :scriptRequirements, :scriptDescription, :scriptCode)');

    // Create htmlentity variable
    $htmlName = htmlentities($_POST['scriptName']);
    $htmlReq = htmlentities($_POST['scriptRequirements']);
    $htmlDesc = htmlentities($_POST['scriptDescription']);
    $htmlCode = htmlentities($_POST['scriptCode']);

    // Execute Insert SQL prepared statement
    $insertSql->execute(array(
        'scriptName' => $htmlName,
        'scriptRequirements' => $htmlReq,
        'scriptDescription' => $htmlDesc,
        'scriptCode' => $htmlCode));

    // Display success message and page return
    echo "New script uploaded successfully.<br>";
    echo "<a href='newScript.html'>Upload another script</a><br><br>";

    // Create new query to display new data
    $displaySql = $pdoConn->prepare('SELECT * FROM scripts ORDER BY ScriptID DESC LIMIT 1');

    // Execute SELECT query and display results
    $displaySql->execute();
    foreach ($displaySql as $row) {
        echo "<button class='accordion'>
                <h3>".$row['script_name']."</h3>
              </button>
              <div class='panel'>
                <p class='requirements-p'>Requirements: ".$row['script_requirements']."</p>
                <p id='description-p'><span>Description: </span>".$row['script_description']."</p>
                <code>".$row['script_code']."</code>
              </div>";
    }
```

The form I'm using to upload data looks like this:

```
<article id="main-article">
    <h1>Add New Script</h1>
    <div id="form-envelope-div">
        <div id="envelope-inner-div">
            <form id="script-form" action="uploadNewScript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="script-div">
                    <label class="input_label">Title: </label>
                    <input class="text_input" id="title-input" type="text" placeholder="Title *" name="scriptName" required>

                    <label class="input_label">Requirements: </label>
                    <textarea class="textarea_input" id="requirements-textarea" placeholder="Requirements *" rows="10" cols="30" name="scriptRequirements" required></textarea>

                    <label class="input_label">Description: </label>
                    <textarea class="textarea_input" id="description-textarea" placeholder="Description *" rows="10" cols="30" name="scriptDescription" required></textarea>

                    <label class="input_label">Script: </label>
                    <textarea class="textarea_input" id="code-textarea" placeholder="Script *" rows="10" cols="30" name="scriptCode" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="submit-div">
                    <input id="button-input" type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Upload New Property">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Here are two examples of the user input. The first example script is short and has no problem inserting into the database. Example 1:

- **Name**: SSL CSR Requests
- **Requirements**: PowerShell v3 and up.
- **Description**: This uses PS to return all CSRs generated on the server as well as the Creation Date.
- **Code**: Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\REQUEST\ | Sort-Object -Property Subject | fl Subject,@{n='Creation Date';e={$_.'geteffectivedatestring'()}}

The second example script is much more complex and will not insert at all if I use htmlentites. If I try skipping htmlentities and insert directly from $_POST, it will only insert the beginning: *$source =* Also, when I inserted the script directly into the database using PhpMyAdmin, I had no problems whatsoever. It even display in HTML correctly. Example 2 Code input:

```
$source = “C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\”
            $destination = "E:\IISLogBackups_$(Get-Date -format M).zip"
            Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
            [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)
            $logs = ls –Path  “C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\*” –Recurse | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)}
            $logs | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Alisha, try by inserting it in static way first and see what happens , may be max char issue not sure but have a try.

Comment: Don't save it using `htmlentities` it's better to use that when displaying.  Modifying the content can cause issues, such as double encoding it etc.

Comment: Does the long PowerShell script appear in the HTML code of the page? If no, is the script insterted to the database cell? Could you please give an example of the script and the table schema?

Comment: `But, when I tried to insert a long PowerShell script, it just left the table column blank` sounds like a schema issue, what field type are you using `VARCHAR(200)`? (thats a joke)  You should get an error, well in MySQL 5.6+ (I think) older version may just truncate the data.  In other words make sure the field can accommodate the size of the text.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix If a text is too long for a column, it is cut but not discarded

Comment: Not in the current version of MySQL with strict sql set., it throws an error.  Caused a lot of issues at work, that "fix" did.  `For truncation of nonspace characters, you can cause an error to occur (rather than a warning) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode.`  I think it's the default as of mysql `5.6` or `5.7` I forget.  Here you go https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/18/upgrading-to-mysql-5-7-beware-of-the-new-strict-mode/

Comment: As a test, take it out of PHP, take the query and try to manually run it in something like PHPmyAdmin.  This way you can isolate the issue to just the query or something in the PHP code.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix if it throws an error, then there is no insert at all

Comment: Did you try putting `:` in front of the array keys in the `execute` such as `:scriptCode` there is a setting that allows you to use them without it.  I never rely on it, but i'm just grasping at straws now.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, I tried inserting the script directly into the database through PhpMyAdmin as you suggested and I had no problems. It even displays properly in HTML. I believe that suggests the problem is in my PHP.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, I tried inserting the data directly from $_POST, but then, instead of inserting nothing, it only inserted the beginning of the user input: $source =

Comment: @Finesse I edited my question with the html form and example user input to help clarify. Everything inserts and displays properly except the longer script.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the table column field type is `text`.

Comment: Try `set_time_limit(0)` then get back to us.

Comment: @PHPglue, I'm sorry, could you please explain what benefit `set_time_limit(0)` will have and how I should be implementing it?

Comment: Put it at the top of your PHP page, where you do your PowerShell execution. If it works then you know the problem has to do with your PHP time limit. Default is 30 seconds. If PowerShell takes longer that that, that's your problem.

Comment: @PHPglue, unfortunately that didn't seem to help.

Comment: @AlishaNarvaez put your script column mandatory and not nullable in your table schema and in your php code, use try catch to generate error and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOT of debugging, I finally figured out how to solve my problem. For whatever reason, the `$_POST` variable for the `textarea` field was having a problem reading the hyphens in the user input. Once the input reached the `$_POST` variable, it was already too late to fix the problem using `htmlentities` or any equivalent PHP function. So, I created a JavaScript function that automatically replaces all the hyphens with the HTML entity `&#8221` before the user input is submitted. Here's what that JavaScript looks like:

```
document.getElementById('code-textarea').value.replace('-', '&#8211;');
```